# Jenkins deploying to multiple servers based on data in a SQL Table

Tags: java, shell, maven, deployment, jenkins

Presently, I have many jenkins jobs deploying war files to multiple servers using jboss as maven plugin. I have created multiple post build maven goals to deploy to multiple instances. To enhance the setup, I need to read the data from a SQL table where the mapping exist for each project and instances. Based on the data, I need to dynamically change the instances(undeploy from previous instance and deploy on new instance) and do hot deployment. Any thoughts?

Comment: any suggestion on this?

Comment: Can someone help me with a suggestion?

Comment: some help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using DB, I would suggest you to use a simple source repo, e.g. git repo.  You can have such mapping data in that file.

So when you do deployment, Jenkins would checkout the repo. Your script could read it and do deployment. The script could be bash, ruby or anything you think it's easy.  The script for deployment could be put into the same source repo as well.

Later on, if you need to do any change, you just change the repo and push the change.

The whole idea is infrastructure as code. You should put everything into source control. Jenkins will be a single tool to invoke the script from your source repo.

Comment: Our infrastructure already has a top level DB being populated with node vs project information. I need to pull the data from this table and check if the node has changed. If there is a change, I need to undeploy from previous node and deploy on the new node. A node can have multiple instances.